# React Native error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: react-native

I start React native app and for my first component i have error :

```
React Native error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined.
```

I tried all imports type but the same error.Help please

in my index.js 
[Index capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM72W.jpg)

import MeteoPage from './MeteoPage';

```
render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Météo',
          component: MeteoPage
        }}
        />
    );
  }
```

in my MeteoPage.js
[MeteoPage capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIRSz.jpg)
export default class MeteoPage extends Component

Comment: Can you show the code for MeteoPage?

Comment: What happens if you add `console.log(MeteoPage)` as the first line of your `render` method of the `myApp` component?

Comment: I finally used react-navigation and it's OK. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

don't use `export default` for your MeteoPage . you must export like this :

```
export {MeteoPage}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i did it but i have the same error.